# SQL Server let the sql client decide the language (or force it)

Tags: sql-server

I have 2 SQL Server Management Studio clients, one in French, one in US English.

I have 2 database servers, that I suppose are configured absolutely identical, but it looks like it's not the case !

```
select @@LANGUAGE
```

from the French Management Studio on server 1 returns `us_english`.

```
select @@LANGUAGE
```

from the English Management Studio on server 1 returns `us_english`.

```
select @@LANGUAGE
```

from the French Management Studio on server 2 returns `français(french)`.

```
select @@LANGUAGE
```

from the English Management Studio on server 2 returns `us_english`.

How can this be ?

Is there a parameter somewhere on the server that says server 1 does not care about the client language, but server 2 does ?

Comment: What does `sqlcmd -S <server> -Q "select @@language"` yield? Just to determine if it's Management Studio doing something interesting, or any client connection.

Comment: Cross posted: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37680236/sql-server-let-the-sql-client-decide-the-language-or-force-it

Comment: @JeroenMostert it's any client connection. I use MS cause I know for sure which language it uses and where I can change it (tools/options/general/international settings).

Comment: @TomV yes I know, I posted here in dba on advice from Jeroen, should I close the original one ?

Comment: Are you using the same login in all cases? Are you connecting to a database that uses containment? Does a profiler trace yield anything interesting in terms of code executing automatically that could change the language?

Comment: yes, same login. connection to master db. no use of containment. I have to check for the profiler trace cause I don't know how to do that.

Comment: Well, I'm puzzled, to say the least. However, if you want to *force* the use of a particular language, there's a simple solution -- use the `language` keyword in the connection string (both ADO and ODBC) or the `SET LANGUAGE` command in a query. This may not solve your problem if you really do intend the language to vary (which I wouldn't recommend, though).

Comment: many thanks Jeroen for trying. Yes I was aware of the set language. I have an idea, as I was saying in the post of Martin's answer, but it has been deleted in the meantime. The two logins have the same default language, but not the same default database. on server 1, the login have master. on server 2, the login have the application database. I have to make some tests to see if it can come from there.

Comment: It could but shouldn't, because language isn't a database/user setting unless the database is contained. Let us know what you find.